# Two-sample t-test between coefficient from regression on two different samples

Tags: regression, t-test, sampling, stata

I am trying to perform a two sample t-test on the regression coefficients for event dummies between two portfolio's (portfolio 1: Top portfolio and portfolio 2: Bad portfolio)

The Do file I wrote for now provides a regression output that looks the following:
Click image for larger version

[image]

I am struggling to find a way/methodology to store this information whereafter I can easily use it to perform the two sample t-tests for every respective coefficients and finally between the sum of the coefficients, as I would run exactly the same regression for the "bad" portfolio.

What information should I store? Is it sufficient to just save the coefficients and the Std. Err., or do I need to save the weighted (market cap) average daily returns of the portfolio's? or maybe the returns from all the companies in the sample with an indicator if they are part of portfolio "good" or "bad"?

Comment: Use surreg or suest. You are looking for seemingly unrelated estimates/regression

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand the question, but some thoughts:

Since it looks like you are using Stata, you could use suest for testing equality of coefficients across regressions (on the two portfolios).

I think you're hinting that another way to do it would be to run a pooled regression with firms in both portfolios, where you'd include all the variables you already have in the regression as well as their interaction with a dummy for being in one of the portfolios. You may need to address heteroscedasticity in that regression (if firms in the good and bad portfolios have different variance).

The estimates will be the same whether you estimate two separate regressions or a pooled regressions with a full set of interactions with group dummies (e.g. the constant term in the regression on just the 'bad' portfolio should equal the constant term + the 'bad' dummy in a pooled regression). I am less sure about whether the tests are equivalent, especially in finite samples. Also not aware of general theory saying one method is better than the other, though the pooled regression seems simpler and more transparent to me.

On somehow including market cap - I think it is not so much a statistical question and more about what question you're asking whether you want to weight firms equally or by their market cap.